# Bash %s format specifier eliminates spaces in string on print out

Tags: bash, printf, string-formatting

I am starting to use the `printf` instead of `echo`. My first forray into `printf %s` is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
danny=$(tail -1 /come/and/play/with/US.log| ~/walt/convert_gm_est)
printf "%s" $danny
```

```
08:02.020ZINFO<-casper/casperbox001wowSYSSTATS[sz=21,tag=0,aux=0]process_log2221397800
```

It eliminates all the spaces in the string. So I added a space after the format specifier. the string looks nicer with the spaces plus I could rip out the time with awk very easily. I don't see anything about this on the interwebs. I tried a `"%s\s"` and that did not work.  Is this standard procedure for using format specifiers - use a space after `%s`? Is this the way to do it or am I missing something?

```
#!/bin/bash
danny=$(tail -1 /come/and/play/with/US.log| ~/walt/convert_gm_est)
printf "%s " $danny
```

```
08:02.020Z INFO <- casper/casperbox001wow SYSSTATS[sz=21, tag=0, aux=0] process_log 2221397 80 0 casper@casperbox001wow:~$
```

Comment: Quote your variables! Compare `printf "%s" foo bar baz` to `printf "%s" "foo bar baz"`. (Tip: Use http://www.shellcheck.net/ to catch such errors early.)

Comment: Why `danny`? It's cute, but cute variable names get old really fast. Properly naming your identifiers is actually an important part of programming. Code with `sharon=richard*betty` is needlessly hard to read when you could say completely transparently `sum=reported_hours*hourly_rate` (throw in `ted` for discount and `marianne` for currency and most people will give up trying to understand already).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the shell evaluates:

```
printf "%s" $danny
```

the shell will expand the value of the variable `danny` and then split it into words. It will also expand globs in those words. Once that is done, the expression will look something like this (quotes added for clarification):

```
printf '%s' '08:02.020Z' 'INFO' '<-' 'casper/casperbox001' 'wow0' 'SYSSTATS'...
```

`printf` repeats its format string until all of the arguments are consumed. So using the format string `%s` causes the arguments to be concatenated without intervening spaces.

You probably meant to quote `$danny` so that it would be presented as a single argument to printf:

```
printf "%s" "$danny"
```